# Error when trying to access dask datafame - ValueError: Length of passed values is 0, index implies

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm getting above the error when trying to compute a dask dataframe. Here's what I'm doing(taking a pandas dataframe, then converting year to datatime then merging it with another dataframe):

```
from dask import dataframe as dd 


#setup variables
df1x =  dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=4).reset_index() # cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(FullMerge)  
df2x =  dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=4).reset_index() #cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(emissions)    

# add year
df1x['year'] =  dd.to_datetime(df1x.date_x,unit='ns')  #pd.to_datetime(df1['date_x'])
df2x['year'] =  dd.to_datetime(df2x.year,unit='ns') 

#we must rename emissions DF values to match fullMerge so data can merge correctly
df2x = df2x.rename(columns={'reference_name': 'Name'})

# map revenueOut to df1 #set it to value
df1x['value'] = df1x[['year', 'Name']].merge(df2x, how='left').revenueOutput
```

It seems to work(no errors) but when I want to view the results, I get above error:
df1x.to_csv('myfiles.csv', single_file = True)

I get this stack trace(if it helps):

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-78b6500075c4> in <module>
----> 1 df1x.to_csv('myfiles.csv', single_file = True)
      2 # dd.compute(Full_df)

20 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
   1344         from .io import to_csv
   1345 
-> 1346         return to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
   1347 
   1348     def to_json(self, filename, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py in to_csv(df, filename, single_file, encoding, mode, name_function, compression, compute, scheduler, storage_options, header_first_partition_only, **kwargs)
    787         )
    788     if compute:
--> 789         delayed(values).compute(scheduler=scheduler)
    790         return [f.path for f in files]
    791     else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    164         dask.base.compute
    165         """
--> 166         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    167         return result
    168 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    435     keys = [x.__dask_keys__() for x in collections]
    436     postcomputes = [x.__dask_postcompute__() for x in collections]
--> 437     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    438     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    439 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/threaded.py in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     82         get_id=_thread_get_id,
     83         pack_exception=pack_exception,
---> 84         **kwargs
     85     )
     86 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    484                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    485                     else:
--> 486                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    487                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    488                 state["cache"][key] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/local.py in reraise(exc, tb)
    314     if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    315         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 316     raise exc
    317 
    318 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/local.py in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    220     try:
    221         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 222         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    223         id = get_id()
    224         result = dumps((result, id))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/optimization.py in __call__(self, *args)
    980         if not len(args) == len(self.inkeys):
    981             raise ValueError("Expected %d args, got %d" % (len(self.inkeys), len(args)))
--> 982         return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
    983 
    984     def __reduce__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/core.py in get(dsk, out, cache)
    149     for key in toposort(dsk):
    150         task = dsk[key]
--> 151         result = _execute_task(task, cache)
    152         cache[key] = result
    153     result = _execute_task(out, cache)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/core.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/utils.py in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     28 def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
     29     if kwargs:
---> 30         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     31     else:
     32         return func(*args)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in apply_and_enforce(*args, **kwargs)
   5072     func = kwargs.pop("_func")
   5073     meta = kwargs.pop("_meta")
-> 5074     df = func(*args, **kwargs)
   5075     if is_dataframe_like(df) or is_series_like(df) or is_index_like(df):
   5076         if not len(df):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py in partitioning_index(df, npartitions)
    604         An array of int64 values mapping each record to a partition.
    605     """
--> 606     return hash_object_dispatch(df, index=False) % int(npartitions)
    607 
    608 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/utils.py in __call__(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    504         """
    505         meth = self.dispatch(type(arg))
--> 506         return meth(arg, *args, **kwargs)
    507 
    508     @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py in hash_object_pandas(obj, index, encoding, hash_key, categorize)
    470 ):
    471     return pd.util.hash_pandas_object(
--> 472         obj, index=index, encoding=encoding, hash_key=hash_key, categorize=categorize
    473     )
    474 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/util/hashing.py in hash_pandas_object(obj, index, encoding, hash_key, categorize)
    134         h = _combine_hash_arrays(hashes, num_items)
    135 
--> 136         h = Series(h, index=obj.index, dtype="uint64", copy=False)
    137     else:
    138         raise TypeError(f"Unexpected type for hashing {type(obj)}")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    312                     if len(index) != len(data):
    313                         raise ValueError(
--> 314                             f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
    315                             f"index implies {len(index)}."
    316                         )

ValueError: Length of passed values is 0, index implies 41478.
```

I'm not sure what to do as the pandas version is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the following line is not something dask will handle well:

```py
df1x['value'] = df1x[['year', 'Name']].merge(df2x, how='left').revenueOutput
```

The reason is that partitions must be aligned when assigning the variable (`df1x['value'] =  ...`), while merge (in general) does not yield the same alignment (`df1x[['year', 'Name']].merge(df2x, how='left')`). This is not an issue when all data is in memory.

If `df2y` defined below fits into memory, then one possible option is to do it with `.map_partitions`:

```py
# make sure this fits into memory
df2y = df2x[['year', 'Name', 'revenueOutput']].compute()

def add_value(df):
    df = df.merge(df2y, how='left')
    df['value'] = df['revenueOutput']
    return df
df1x = df1x.map_partitions(add_value)
```

If `df2y` does not fit into memory, then it might be possible to do an explicit dask merge and then use the merged dataframe for further analysis:

```py
merged_df = dd.merge(df1x, df2x, on=['year', 'Name'], how='left')
merged_df['value'] = merged_df['revenueOutput']
# I assume that the line above is needed for some further
# transformation, but if that's not the case, then
# a simple column rename is more efficient
```